# Вывести элементы и атрибуты из xml

Tags: c#, xml

**Дано:** Есть большой xml файл.

**Вопрос:** Как вывести элементы и атрибуты, если структура дерева не известна?

Comment: Насколько большой? Считать весь файл в `XDocument` не выйдет?

Comment: 410 строчек, я даже не знаю , я новичёк

Comment: 410 — это очень маленький файл. Понял, напишу, как доберусь до компьютера.

Comment: буду очень благодарен

Comment: Готово, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо выручили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(<тут путь к вашему XML>);
        DisplayElement(doc.Document.Root);
    }

    static void DisplayElement(XElement e, int indentLevel = 0)
    {
        DisplayNameAndAttributes(e, indentLevel);
        foreach (var child in e.Nodes())
        {
            var childElement = child as XElement;
            if (childElement != null)
                DisplayElement(childElement, indentLevel + 1);

            var contentText = child as XText;
            if (contentText != null)
                DisplayContent(contentText, indentLevel + 1);

            // тут можно проверять другие типы узлов, например, комментарии
        }
    }

    static void DisplayNameAndAttributes(XElement e, int indentLevel)
    {
        var indentString = new string(' ', 2 * indentLevel);
        Console.Write($"{indentString}* {e.Name}");
        if (e.HasAttributes)
        {
            Console.Write(" [");
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var attr in e.Attributes())
            {
                if (!first)
                    Console.Write(", ");
                first = false;
                Console.Write($"{attr.Name} = {attr.Value}");
            }
            Console.Write(']');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void DisplayContent(XText contentText, int indentLevel)
    {
        var indentString = new string(' ', 2 * indentLevel);
        var text = contentText.Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"{indentString}<text content: {text}>");
    }
}
```

Для стандартного Майкрософтовского [тестового примера](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx) выдаёт:

```
* catalog
  * book [id = bk101]
    * author
      <text content: Gambardella, Matthew>
    * title
      <text content: XML Developer's Guide>
    * genre
      <text content: Computer>
    * price
      <text content: 44.95>
    * publish_date
      <text content: 2000-10-01>
    * description
      <text content: An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.>
  * book [id = bk102]
    * author
      <text content: Ralls, Kim>
    * title
      <text content: Midnight Rain>
    * genre
      <text content: Fantasy>
    * price
      <text content: 5.95>
    * publish_date
      <text content: 2000-12-16>
    * description
      <text content: A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.>
  * book [id = bk103]
```

и т. д.